# Number type suffixes in C#

Tags: c#, double, decimal

I searched for this question first before posting, but all I got was based on C++.
Here is my question:
Is a double with f suffix normal in c#? If yes, why and how is this possible?

Have a look at this code:

```
double d1 = 1.2f;
double d2 = 2.0f;

Console.WriteLine("{0}", d2 - d1);

decimal dm1 = 1.2m;
decimal dm2 = 2.0m;

Console.WriteLine("{0}", dm2 - dm1);
```

The answers for the first calculation is 0.799999952316284 with f suffix instead of 0.8. Also, when I change the f to a d which I think should be the normal way, it gives a correct answer of 0.8.

Comment: f is the suffix for a float, not a double.

Comment: @martin_costello he is aware of that (read along), that's not the issue.

Comment: When dealing with floating point, it is incorrect to say that the "correct" answer is 0.8; not all values are even representable in floating point. All that exists is "close enough". If you need human-style decimal rounding: use `decimal`, not floating point.

Comment: If the question is "it it a common thing to do to initialize a `double` variable using a `float` literal?" then I think the answer is no. It's not common in *my* experience.

Answer (score 2):

The right hand expression is evaluated as `float` and then "deposited" in a `double` variable. Nothing wrong or weird here. I think the difference in result has to do with the precision of the two data types.

Referring to your appreciation of the "correct answer", the fact that `0.8` came out "correct" is not because you changed from a float literal to a double literal. That's just a better approximation of the result. The "correct" result is indeed coming from the second expression, the one using `decimal` types.

Answer (score 1):

The `f` suffix stand for `float` and not `double`. So `1.2f` is a single precission floating point number which will be saved to a double directly after creating it because of an implicit cast to double.

The inprecission you are getting seems to be happening there and not at the calculation as it seems to be working with `1.2d`.

Such behaviour is normal when using floating-point values. Use `decimal` if you do not want such behaviour as you already did in you examples yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Double and Float both are **binary** numbers.

The Problem is not their precision but the *kind of numbers* they can store in an exact manner, which must be binary, too. Change 1.2f to 0.5f of 0.25f or 0.125f and so an and you will see 'correct' results. But any number with different factorials must be stored in an **approximation**. There is a '3' *hidden* in the 1.2 and you can't store in in a float or double. If you try, only an approximation will be stored.

Decimals are actually storing decimal digits and you won't see any approximations there as long as you don't leave the decimal realm. If you try to store, say, 1/3 in a decimal, it'll have to approximate as well..